# Why do two things lose contact only when normal = 0?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, spring, oscillators

Why do two things lose contact only when normal = 0? 
For example, I was doing a question in which a massless plank was attached to a spring. The plank also had a block of mass m kept on it. The whole system was in SHM. Now it was asked to calculate the amplitude where the block will lose the contact. I understood that the normal may become 0 at the amplitude. But , at the mean position the plank and the block both had maximum velocity and after this instant block will not slow down and the plank will slow down. Then, due to inertia of motion it should leave the plank at the mean position only. I don't understand where am I going wrong.

Comment: "Normal" is a direction. How can a direction become 0? Do you mean the normal force? (Please edit your question to clarify what you're asking)

Answer (score 2):

I find it helpful to remember that "normal force" and "friction force" are not really fundamental forces.  They're really aggregations of a very large number of small electrostatic forces.  The plank and block will interact electrostatically at any distance, but the effects fall off *dramatically* once the objects are a short distance apart.  In this case, short may be measured in nanometers.

Remember that you are really just working with a model of some real physical contraption.  What we find is that in the real physical contraption, there's two easy domains.  If the normal force is reasonably larger than 0, then these objects will stay in the "very close" range where these electrostatic forces are strong.  If the normal force is really close to zero (nano-newtons) because the objects are more than a few nanometers apart, then these miniscule interactions really won't matter much.

In the real world, there's a small region in between where all sorts of effects start to matter.  For example, your block can deform and spring back.  When you are in the "normal force greater than 0" region, this is typically negligible.  The deformation might account for um of movement.  Likewise, when the block isn't in contact, the deformation itself is basically none at all.  But in between, there's a frustrating little gap where neither of those simple models work.  We call this the region where we are "losing contact."  It happens close enough to "normal force equals 0" that we can just call that the definition of losing contact.

This event can occur anywhere the acceleration opposes the velocity.  It all depends on your initial conditions.  If your initial conditions set it up to lose contact quickly, it may not make it to "maximum velocity" before it loses contact and you have to switch to a model where there is no contact between the block and the plank.

Answer (score 1):

They don't lose contact "only when N = 0".  But if they lose contact N must equal 0.  These two statements are not the same.  When we solve problems like that we are imposing conditions that are consistent with losing contact.  When contact is lost it is necessary that N = 0.  I am not sure how to interpret the rest of your description.  If something seems wrong can you post your solution for review?

Comment: Sir, at the mean position, the block should leave the plank because of inertia of motion. Why it is not doing so?

Comment: Can you show your work.  What defines the "mean" position.  Get a diagram in there.

Answer (score 0):

Let down be the positive direction.

The equation of motion for the block, mass $m$, whilst in contact with the plank is $mg-N=ma$ where $N$ is the normal reaction on the block due to the plank, $g$ is the gravitational field strength and $a$ is the acceleration of the block and the plank.

The maximum downward acceleration the **block** can have is when $N=0$ leading to an acceleration of $g$.
$N$ cannot be negative as this would mean that the plank is pulling the block down.

So what happens if the downward acceleration of the **plank** is greater than $g$?